# Is there Typescript syntactic sugar for getting types of private properties/methods?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Looking to the masters :)
I'm learning Typescript and want to be able to get private & protected properties/method types easily inside the class

Edit: found `ClassName['method']` but is there any syntactic sugar for something like `this.methodName`?

Example:

```
private defaultOptions: Pick<Options, 'bar' | 'baz'> = {/* defaults */}

private getOtherOptions(): Omit<Options, keyof this['defaultOptions']> {
 // format...
}

public handleSomething(event: any): void {
 const map = new Map<string, ReturnType<this['getOtherOptions']>>()
 ...
 const options: Options = Object.assign({}, map.get(event.id), this.defaults)
}
```

I have tried this so far...

Take the example:

```
class MyClass {
    public foo: string = 'foo'
    private bar: string = 'bar'
    protected baz: string = 'baz'

    constructor() { }

    public getBar(): string {
        return this.bar
    }

    private getBaz(): string {
        return this.baz
    }

    private getString(): string {
        return 'hello'
    }

    public handleEvent(event: any): any {
        let xfoo: this['foo'] = this.foo // Okay
        let xbar: this['bar'] = this.bar // Private or protected member 'bar' cannot be accessed on a type parameter.
        let xbar2: MyClass['bar'] = this.bar // Okay
        let xbaz: this['baz'] = this.baz // Private or protected member 'baz' cannot be accessed on a type parameter.
        let xbaz2: MyClass['baz'] = this.baz // Okay

        let fnBar: ReturnType<this['getBar']> = 'hello' // Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<this["getBar"]>'
        let fnBar2: ReturnType<MyClass['getBar']> = 'hello' // Okay

        let fnBaz: ReturnType<this['getBaz']> = 'hello'
        //                    ^ Private or protected member 'getBaz' cannot be accessed on a type parameter.
        //   ^ Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ReturnType<this["getBaz"]>'
        let fnBaz2: ReturnType<typeof this['getBaz']> = 'hello' // Cannot find name 'this'
        let fnBaz3: ReturnType<(typeof this)['getBaz']> = 'hello' // Cannot find name 'this'
        let fnBaz4: ReturnType<(typeof this['getBaz'])> = 'hello' // Cannot find name 'this'
        let fnBaz5: ReturnType<MyClass['getBaz']> = 'hello' // Okay
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant to put `let foo = this['foo']` instead of `let foo: this['foo']`

Comment: The colon sets the type, not the value

Comment: @BrandonDyer updated the example. No, I meant to set the type by referencing the class property and then initialize it to `this.foo` or other.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. How is the second snippet related to the first?

Comment: @JonasWilms updated the question for better reading.

Comment: still don't get it.

Comment: I think you mean `let foo: typeof this['foo'] = this.foo`, which isn't necessary, because it'll infer the type automatically.